# How to read gmails of all users in same domain using impersonation/service Account (like in Exchange api) in c#

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to develop one c# console app to read emails using service account without user's consent but I am not getting proper guidance how to achieve it? I have followed steps as per [domain wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) but it redirects to authorization screen to ask permission.

Actually I want to develop solution like [Exchange API streaming notification](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/12/22/working-with-streaming-notifications-by-using-the-ews-managed-api/) where I can read email when new event occurred on server and insert it into database using impersonated user.

Comment: How are you going to equate Windows Domain Users with _Gmail_ in order for impersonation to work?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to achieve this.   It sounds like you are using the Oauth2 code and not the service account code.    Domain wide deligatoin on service accounts only works with a gsuite account and the gmail accounts created by that.  Which as @MickyD mentioned has nothing to do with windows domain users.